# Bootstrap double list

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site project where I would like to show users and the elements they are assigned to. For this purpose, I think the best solution would be that of having two vertical list, one next to the other.

The first list should contain all the users. Once a user is clicked, the second list will be filled with the elements of that user. Potentially an element can contain more than one column: name, details, ... So it will be much more wider than the user.

Is there any type of panel/list/table or any other Bootstrap component that is able to display extended information in a list? Like in this case, showing the elements of a user.

Any ideas or references to Components or Snippets you may know would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Like this way http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for tables, you can use the [bootstrap tables](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) you just have to add `class table` in the `table-tag`. What you can do is to initially not have anything in the `<td>` names and use `Javascript` to write the user infos using a `trigger`: `on-click` maybe?

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td>Users</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Infos</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

So I think there are many ways to implement what you want to do.. I can think of two cases:

- case 1: you have known data of users that don't change and
- case 2: you are taking the data from the database and you don't know the exact data...

### Case 1: when you have the exact data when building the website

if you have the exact data, you might want to use a [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), a [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or a [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) which you can find on the links I provided.

### Case 2: when you don't have the exact data

you might still want to use a `tooltip`, a `popover` or a `modal` but this time around you will have to write a `javascript function` that writes the data unto the `tooltip`, `popover` or `modal`.

---

### Advice for stackoverflow

Before asking questions, try something, tell us what you tried, show us a piece of code using **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** or **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/)** or any other online editor/coding playground. And we can help you. Questions with answers too broad are usually flagged, same as implementation questions and debugging questions.